# Как добавить, редактировать, сохранить объект на сервлете

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, servlet

Реализовал простой справочник книг на JSP странице, данные которого тянутся из БД OracleSQL с помощью Hibernate. На этой же странице есть форма с полями (`input`) `"name"`, `"author"`, `"year"` и кнопка submit для добавления в БД.  Напротив каждой записи в справочнике есть кнопки `update`, `delete`.  Добавлять и удалять данные из базы получается без проблем, а вот сделать update не получается.

Проблема в том, что на сервлете в методе `doPost` не срабатывает условие `if` (через дебаг узнал, ), а именно строчка `else if (action.equals("update")) .....`  Сразу скажу , что `ID` нужной книжки подхватывает верный, с ним проблем нет, голову не ломайте (дебажил).

Я допускаю, что возможно пытаюсь выполнить совершенно наивную операцию, но помогите разобраться как все-таки реализовать на одной и той же JSP странице  вывод данных из БД  и редактирование. Пока что получается удалить и добавить. Прошу тыкнуть пальцем где что нужно добавить или изменить. Заранее спасибо всем за развернутые ответы.   За практический совет с меня две бутылки пиво на ваш кошелек)

Приведу все страницы кода, но **в первую очередь сам сервлет (`Servletclass.class`) и JSP класс (`BookStore.jsp`).**

```
 package ru.home.echo;


import ru.home.echo.control.ControlClass;
import ru.home.echo.entity.Books;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ServletClass extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        ControlClass controlClass= new ControlClass();
        RequestDispatcher rd = null;
        resp.setContentType("text/html");

        if (req.getParameter("action" )!=null) {

            if (req.getParameter("action").equals("delete")) {

                int id = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("id"));
                Books books = new Books();
                books.setId(id);

                controlClass.deleteBook(books);

                List<Books> book = controlClass.getAllData();
                req.setAttribute("Books", book);
                rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("BookStore.jsp");
            }

            else if (req.getParameter("action").equals("update")){

                int id = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("id").toString());


                Books book = controlClass.getBooksById(id);
                req.setAttribute("booking", book);
                req.setAttribute("action", "update");

                List<Books> books = controlClass.getAllData();
                req.setAttribute("Books", books);

                rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("BookStore.jsp");

            }
        }
        else {

            List<Books> books = controlClass.getAllData();
            req.setAttribute("Books", books);
            rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("BookStore.jsp");
        }

        rd.forward(req, resp);
    }


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String action = req.getParameter("action").toString();
        resp.setContentType("text/html");

        RequestDispatcher rd=null;
        if(action.equals("new")) {
            Books books = new Books();
            ControlClass controlClass = new ControlClass();

            req.setAttribute("booking", books);

            books.setName(req.getParameter("bookname").toString());
            books.setAuthor(req.getParameter("bookauthor").toString());
            books.setYear(Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("bookyear")));

            controlClass.saveBook(books);


            List<Books> booksList = controlClass.getAllData();
            req.setAttribute("Books", booksList);
            rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("BookStore.jsp");
        }

        else if(action.equals("update")){

            Books book= new Books();
            book.setName(req.getParameter("bookname").toString());
            book.setAuthor(req.getParameter("bookauthor").toString());
            book.setYear(Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("bookyear")));

            book.setId(Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("bookingid").toString()));

            ControlClass controlClass= new ControlClass();
            controlClass.updateBook(book);

            List<Books>booksList= controlClass.getAllData();
            req.setAttribute("Books",booksList);
            rd=req.getRequestDispatcher("BookStore.jsp");

        }



        rd.forward(req,resp);

    }
}
```

**Страница BookStore.jsp:**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>BooksStore</title>
    <style type="text/css">

        .tdser {background: #cccccc;}


        td {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            padding: 10px 5px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 1px;
            overflow: hidden;
            word-break: normal;
            border-color: black;
            color: #333;
            background-color: #fff;
        }

        table { border-collapse: collapse;
            border-spacing: 0;
            border-color: #ccc;}

    </style>

</head>
<body>

<table >
    <tr id="toptr">
        <td class="tdser">ID</td>
        <td class="tdser">NAME</td>
        <td class="tdser">AUTHOR</td>
        <td class="tdser">YEAR</td>
    </tr>

<c:forEach items="${Books}" var="book">
    <tr id="downtr">
        <td>${book.id}</td>
        <td>${book.name}</td>
        <td>${book.author}</td>
        <td>${book.year}</td>
        <td><a href="/books?action=delete&id=${book.id}">delete</a></td>
        <td><a href="/books?action=update&id=${book.id}">update</a></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>


</table>
<br>
<br>
<form action="/books" method="post">



    Book name:<input type="text" name="bookname" value="${booking.name}"><br><br>
    Book author:<input type="text" name="bookauthor" value="${booking.author}"><br><br>
    Book year:<input type="text" name="bookyear" value="${booking.year}"><br><br>
    <input type="hidden" value="new" name="action">
    <input type="hidden" value="${booking.id}" name="bookingid">
              <input type="submit" value="submit">

</form>




</body>
</html>
```

**Класс Books.class  (entity):**

```
package ru.home.echo.entity;


import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOKS")
public class Books {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "bookIdGen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "bookIdGen", sequenceName = "BOOK_SEQ",allocationSize = 1)

long id;

@Column(name = "NAME")
String name;

@Column(name = "AUTHOR")
String author;

@Column(name = "YEAR")
int year;


    public Books() {
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Entity{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", author='" + author + '\'' +
                ", year=" + year +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Класс ControlClass (контроллер):**

```
package ru.home.echo.control;


import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import ru.home.echo.DAO.GetSession;
import ru.home.echo.entity.Books;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ControlClass {



    public List<Books> getAllData(){

        GetSession getSession= new GetSession();
        Session session= getSession.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        List<Books>book=new ArrayList<>();
        Query query=session.createQuery("from Books book");
        book= query.list();

        return  book;


    }

    public void saveBook(Books book) {
        GetSession getSession= new GetSession();
        Session session= getSession.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(book);
        t.commit();
        System.out.println("inserted.......");

    }


    public void deleteBook(Books book) {
        GetSession getSession= new GetSession();
        Session session= getSession.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
        session.delete(book);
        t.commit();


    }


    public void updateBook(Books book) {
        GetSession getSession= new GetSession();
        Session session= getSession.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
        session.update(book);
        t.commit();

    }


    public Books getBooksById(int id){

        String query = "from Books book where book.id="+id;

        GetSession getSession= new GetSession();
        Session session= getSession.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        Query query2 = session.createQuery(query);

        Books book= (Books) query2.list().get(0);

        return book;
    }

}
```

**Класс для получение SessionFactory:**

```
package ru.home.echo.DAO;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;


import java.util.Locale;

public class GetSession {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory=createSessionFactory();
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;


    public static SessionFactory createSessionFactory() {
        try {

            Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                    configuration.getProperties()).build();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
            return sessionFactory;
        }

        catch (Throwable ex) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }

    }
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

**И наконец WEB.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>HibernateExampleWithServlets</display-name>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>BooksServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ru.home.echo.ServletClass</servlet-class>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>BooksServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/books</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Ошибку не кидает , просто отрабатывает не корректно. А именно - допустим есть запись в базе name= "Gorec", author="Ivan", year= "1988". При нажатии "update" напротив записи , система кидает на форму для редактирования с заполненными полями. Допустим я меня год с 1988 на 2000, после этого  при нажатии кнопку submit он просто добавляет новую запись Gorec, Ivan, 2000 ( то есть срабатывает условие action = new за место action = update.

Comment: Я ответил на ваш вопрос. Что именно переформулировать ? Вопрос в том как сделать так, чтобы с помощью одной и той же формы и одной кнопки submit можно было как добавлять записи в бд так и редактировать . Просто я знаю как это делается с помощью двух разных страниц ( отдельные страницы для  добавления и редактирования )но мне интересно как все реализовать на одной странице.

Comment: Чуть выше переформулировал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно поменять название акции, вот например как можно сделать с помощью EL

```
<input type="hidden" value="${booking.id == null?'new':'update'}" name="action">
```

Если вы не хотите этого делать в JSP, то можно смотреть на параметр `id` в контроллере или куда глубже уровнях. Но принцип остается тем же самым. Вы даже можете использовать одну акцию для этого в `POST` . с другой стороны если вы уже используете `id` для редактирования, то нет смысла проверять его в JSP. У Hibernate есть метод, который проверяет `id` при сохранении и называется он `saveOrUpdate` насколько мне не изменяет память.

> Когда вы используете `saveOrUpdate()`, Hibernate проверяет, является
>   ли объект переходным (он не имеет свойства идентификатора), и если это
>   так, он сделает его сохраненным, генерируя его идентификатор и назначая
>   его сеансу. Если у объекта есть идентификатор, он будет выполнять
>   `update()`.
>
> Из документации:
>
> `saveOrUpdate()` выполняет следующие действия:
>
> - если объект уже сохранен в этом сеансе, ничего не делает
> - если другой объект, связанный с сеансом, имеет один и тот же идентификатор, генерирует исключение
> - если объект не имеет идентификатора, то выполняет `save()`
> - если идентификатор объекта имеет значение, назначенное для вновь созданного объекта, то выполняет `save()`
> - если объект имеет версию, или, значение свойства `version` - это то же значение, присвоенное вновь созданному объекту, то выполняет
>     `save()`, в противном случае выполняет `update()` объекта.

Comment: Сработало с первым вариантом. Огромное спасибо Роман за подсказку, а все-таки как реализовать в моем коде вариант без изменения jsp. Отблагодарю )

Comment: `if (String.isEmpty(req.getParameter("booking.id")) )//call action "new()" else //call action "update()"`

Comment: пишите мне на почту v.hakobjan@gmail.com  куда вам пиво прислать))

Answer (score 1):

В `ServletClass`, после проверки на `null`, добавьте `System.out.println( req.getParameter("action") )`, и посмотрите, какие параметры поступают при нажатии той или иной кнопки.

И два уточнения по коду, то, что бросилось в глаза. :)

Класс `Books` создаёт экземпляр одной книги, поэтому его лучше назвать `Book`.

В `ControlClass#getAllData()` возвращается `ArrayList`, поэтому здесь `book` лучше переименовать в `books`.

Лучше сразу привыкать называть единичный экземпляр в единственном числе, множественный - во множественном числе.